# How to generate new content with Hyde?

Tags: python, django, jekyll, hyde

I'm starting to learn [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) and I've cloned a few blogs written in Hyde from Github. I can successfully generate these sample blogs in my web browser and serve them locally; however, I can't seem to figure out how to actually generate new content. For example, how can I add a new file in HTML or markdown then serve the file to the site? I see no mention of how to do this in the [docs](http://hyde.github.com/). What am I missing? The directory structure of the sample blogs I'm working with looks like this:

```
---content
    ---about
    ---blog  
---deploy
    ---about
    ---blog
---layout
   ---base.j2
   ---listing.j2
   ---posts.j2
---info.yaml
---site.yaml
```

Can anyone explain how to add either HTML or markdown files and have them served?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hyde does not have commands to create new files. You can create the file in your favorite editor and save it in the correct directory.

For example, if you want a blog post with this url:
http://localhost:8080/blog/2012/01/05/a-new-post,

you have do the following:

1. Create the directory `blog/2010/01/05` under your content folder
2. Use a text editor to create your post
3. Save the file in the directory you created in step 1
4. When you do `hyde gen` and `hyde serve` - you will see the file show up in that url

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and all your work on hyde!

Answer (score 3):

I have written a project called Ghorg which provides a command-line utility for managing a collection of org-mode blog posts, publishing them as html to your hyde site, and invoking the hyde generation and publishing features. This is purely a utility of convenience in that you no longer have to go to your site repository to use it.

I think if, say, some vim users or people who want the post management but not org-mode publish but perhaps markdown or something else (right now its hard-coded to just open emacs) - if those people wanted to help make this more generic then well that'd be great.

[Ghorg: Org for Hyde](http://github.com/dustinlacewell/ghorg)

```
    dlacewell@scarf$ ghorg -h
    usage: ghorg [-h] [-b] [-p] [-s SITE] [--config CONFIG] [-l] [-n [N]] [-P]
                 [-U] [-e] [-t TEMPLATE] [-D]
                 [title [title ...]]

    Manage your Ghorg blog.

    positional arguments:
      title                 all arguments will be joined with hyphen for filename
                            `ghorg post title' => `2012-01-12-post-title.org'

    optional arguments:
       h, --help            show this help message and exit
       b, --build           Perform configured Hyde build step.
       p, --publish         Perform configured Hyde publishing step. (implies -b/--        build)
       s SITE, --site SITE  Path to the root of the Hyde site.
       config CONFIG        Filename of Hyde configuration for building.
       l, --list            List previous posts (-n to change count).
       n [N]                Change number of posts listed (default:5).
       P                    Set post as published.
       U                    Set post as unpublished.
       e                    Mix with -P/-U to edit while changing publishing
                            status.
       t TEMPLATE           Location of template for new posts.
       D                    Delete existing post.
```